# Inheritance in packages

Tags: java, inheritance, package

So I got a compile error, who doesn't find the class `Person` (it works fine if I remove to use the packages)

How can I make `javac` find `Person.class`?

```
package mypackage;

 public class Person {
     private String name;

 public Person(){
   this("Papadopoulos");
  }

 public Person(String name){
   setName(name);
  }

 public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

 public String getName(){
    return( name );
  }

}

public class Student extends Person {
    private String am;
 private String department;

public Student(){
   this("0", "0", "0");
 }

public Student(String am, String department, String name){
   super(name);
   setAm(am);
   setDepartment( department );
}

public void setAm(String am){
   this.am = am;
  }

public String getAm(){
   return( am );
  }

public void setDepartment(String department){
   this.department = department;
  }

public String getDepartment(){
   return( department );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it works fine if I remove to use the packages

You need to Store this file inside `mypackage` folder.

Than go to `command prompt`

```
C:\pathTomyPackage>javac Person.java
```

NOTE: Use `cd folderName` command to go Inside folder upto `.java` file.

or

```
C:\>javac PathToFile\Person.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two classes are in two different packages, you may want to **import** the class Person in the class Student.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that Person and Student class in seperate files.